# Foundation 6, Reveal modal not white

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

im having some issue with the Foundation reveal modals.
When the modal open,its red not white and i cant figure out how to change that there is my code.

```
#exampleModal1.reveal{"data-reveal" => ""}
  %h1 Awesome. I Have It.
  %p.lead Your couch. It is mine.
  %p I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!
  %button.close-button{"aria-label" => "Close modal", "data-close" => "", :type => "button"}
    %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} ×
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution, so i had to go to the _settings.scss and change the reveal background color to white.